# JMX - how to monitor a local and remote cpu usage of an application

Tags: java, jmx, monit

```
Host : serverhost.example.com / 127.0.0.1
Port : 8082
API/Application : Google Chrome / Tomcat deployed application
Monitor : CPU = 35%
          Memory = 30%
```

this is my code snippet :

```
String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:8082/jmxrmi";
JMXConnector jmxc = null;
try {
    JMXServiceURL jmxSvcUrl = new JMXServiceURL(url);
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxSvcUrl, null);
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
    String domains[] = mbsc.getDomains();
    Arrays.sort(domains);
    for (String domain : domains) {
        System.out.println( domain );
    }
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if( jmxc != null )
        try{jmxc.close();}catch(Exception ex){;}
}
```

and i got this error

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ms3.health.core.ResourceManagement.jmxSvcUrl(ResourceManagement.java:137)
    at com.ms3.health.core.ResourceManagement.main(ResourceManagement.java:201)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

please see my code snippet for more details. thanks and more power to everyone.
please let me understand what cause of my issues and how to deal with it.
please see my code snippet for more details. thanks and more power to everyone.
please let me understand what cause of my issues and how to deal with it.

Comment: What problem you can't solve with this code? What error you got?

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin i already edited the questions